# Typescript - assigning a base interface to the extended interface

Tags: typescript

consider the following:

```
interface A {
  x:number;
  y:number
}

interface B extends A { 
  z:number;
}

let v2:B;
// compiler error, as z is not specified
v2 = getSomeA(); // assume this returns interface A
```

I have an `interface B`, that `extends A`. I have a function `getSomeA()` that returns `interface A`. My goal is to assign it to `v2` and then add `v2.z` myself post the call. Obviously, this results in a compiler error. What is the right way to do what I intend to do ? (I could make `z` optional in `interface B` but that is not correct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use object [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for this:

```
v2 = { ...getSomeA(), z: 1 };
```

Comment: Damn that’s hot. I read about this object spread syntax a while ago and thought I’d never find a practical need for it. But here we go!

Comment: Curious - what if getSomeA returned an array of A and I wanted it to assign it to an array of B - is the only option to iterate each returned value and flatten it?

Comment: There's no special syntax for that case, but you could use `map` do do the iteration: `getSomeA().map((a) => ({...a, z: 1}))`